# Binding ExpandoObject in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, binding, expandoobject

In WPF, you can bind against ExpandoObject and other dynamic types:

```
    dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
    o.Foo = "Hello";
    DataContext = o;

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}"/>
```

This doesn't work in Silverlight 5. Is there a way to make it work or does anyone have links to this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Silverlight 5 they didn't add a default mechanism for binding to dynamic objects and instead added a new interface `ICustomTypeProvider`. And that interface wasn't added to an ExpandoObject either, but with expando you should be able to use the indexer binding since it is an `IDictionary<string, object>` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [Foo]}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks especially for mentioning ICustomTypeProvider.